# using the app for a while I get this error Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, swift, memory

The error is because my app really need those views are called by presentViewController. There comes a time that the memory can handle and not break the app.

I used the code below to try to clear the memory and seem to really clean a part but it's still not enough. I need to find a way to disable the previous views without leaving the current view.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
    }
```

this is my presentView method

```
 func showView(){
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("clientsNavigation") as! UINavigationController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: If you're using segues to push to a stack, why not try replacing the view controller instead of pushing?

Comment: I'm not pushing the views. I'm using presentViewController

Comment: How many are you presenting?

Comment: I update my description with the code

Comment: That doesn't answer my question ;)

Comment: sorry. The app does not have views limit

Comment: What does Instruments say?

Comment: How many views are you trying to stack? One or two is fine, 20 is probably your problem. You would be better using a detail view and changing the data presented.

Comment: I need to keep calling ciews but disabling earlier so that they do not remain in memory. Is there any way I keep calling the views by presentViewController but doing dismiss the previous opu clearing them from memory? The app is very complex. I grabbed a code started and now it is not feasible to change the way of display of views. is there any way to free up memory?